# Call Excel Macro using java on a linux box

Tags: java, linux, excel, vbscript, vba

I am not really sure if this is possible but here it goes , I have written an excel macro and i am calling this macro through a vbs. Here is the snippet for the same.

```
Dim objExcel, objWorkbook, ad, FilePath
Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
objExcel.Visible = True
For Each ad In objExcel.AddIns
    If ad.Name = "hello.xla" Then
        FilePath = ad.Path & "\hello.xla"
        Exit For
    End If
Next
objExcel.Workbooks.Open (FilePath)
Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open(WScript.Arguments(0))
objExcel.Run "Test"
objWorkbook.Close
objExcel.Quit
Set objWorkbook = Nothing
Set objExcel = Nothing
WScript.Echo "Finished."
WScript.Quit
```

I am able to do dis. Now i am calling this vb script using java `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start calling.vbs");`

So is it possible to run this excel macro on a linux server? I understand that we cannot call a vbs file on a linux box and also that opening and formatting the excel maybe not possible hence is there maybe a workaround or some other way to call it in linux machine maybe using an sh file ?

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/864116/running-excel-macros-automatically-under-linux and this http://user.services.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?f=20&t=15370

Comment: so i tink wat i conculde from dese links are that this is not possible . Right ? maybe changing it to pearl might help but callin the excel macros are not possible

Comment: My expertise doesn't include Linux but from those links that's what it seems like it :( Maybe you would like to wait for some linux expert to confirm the same?

Comment: yes just hoping against odds now that this may somehow be possible

Answer (score 1):

In theory, you could install Excel and Visual Basic in `wine` and see if your macro runs there. You could then try to execute `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("wine cmd /c start calling.vbs");`

In reality, this sounds like a very complex way of shooting yourself into the foot *badly*.

If you want it to run *reliably* on Linux, stay away from Excel and Visual Basic and start using server technology instead of old office technology.